# Read a text file contents from second line in python

Tags: python

I wrote a python code which executes the bash command and save the output in txt file, now i want to read the txt file which actually contains details from line 2 always, and print true if output exists and send a mail to the user.

Looking for a further solution how I can read specific second line output of file output.txt and print true if the line exists to send a mail to the user otherwise goodbye.

Am very new to this approach, please help with your guidance.
TIA.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("bash command > output.txt", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
p_status = p.wait()
print "command exit status/return code: ", p_status
```

Above code prints the output in the txt file in the below format

```
PID  PPID %CPU     ELAPSED COMMAND
3435 1     0       4-05:20:09
```

Requirement: Read from `"3435 1   0  4-05:20:09 "` this line and print true as line exist and send a mail to user. If not output after  `"PID  PPID %CPU     ELAPSED COMMAND"` it should send no mail

Comment: Hi, i want read from saved output in this case, it is output.txt file which has above output starts from 3435 from the second line, i want to read that and send mail to user if that output exists, if no output in the second line do nothing

Comment: ohh okie, i got your feedback now, sure thanks for the comments, sure i will do it. Actually i thought it will be included in the same code so added that part here as well, but thanks for reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it like this:

```
lines = output.split('\n')
```

Now you can access lines by index e.g. `lines[1]`
 or `lines[1:]`.

You need to remove `> output.txt` from your command to get the output in `output` variable instead of output.txt file

Comment: you can remove `> output.txt` from command as you are getting output in variable no need to save it in file and read again.

Comment: Thanks Amit, i will remove output.txt and try the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create list of lines from a file like this:

```
with open('output.txt') as input_file:
    lines_list = input_file.readlines()    
if len(lines_list) > 1:
    lines_list=lines_list[1:] # drop the first line
    send_mail()
else:
    print ("else condition")
```

you open a file for reading using `"r"` and you build a list of lines. if the list is longer then 1, you build a new list by dropping the first line

Comment: Thanks Yakov and usr2564301, so the above code means i do not have to give fp.close() explicitly? thanks in advance

Comment: That's correct. It is also better, because sometimes you forget to close the file.

Comment: ok great, also at the last of your code, if i want to add one else condition like if
if len(lines_list) > 1:
    lines_list=lines_list[1:] # drop the first line
 print "output exits", lines_list
else:
 print "No output found"

as i want to print this else condition when no output received in the second line